# Layout for a Battleship-game. How to implement the "net"

Tags: android, xml, layout

I was trying to create a Battleship-Layout where you not only have your field, but the field of your enemy on the same screen. I tried for a long time to somehow get it to work with a tablelayout. Thing is I started to doubt that I even used the right layout for my specific need. It s a university Project, so my main purpose is to actually learn something. (In my case how to handle xml files, as I never had to use them before)
Problems I have with my current layout.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufbzv.jpg

1) it s not relative, meaning depending on the display you have a big or a small battlefield.

2) I added image Buttons, their height works well if you add a picture, their width explode's to the end of the row, as it seems the parent isn t the square, but the row.

3) squares aren t actually squares.

4) Seemingly I can t fix a number of columns and rows?

What I need is a customable layout, I can set height, width, place image buttons, that is relative to the size and doesn t explode when I place something within buttons.

Now I know how to use google, adapters and inflate are terms I ve read a few times.
But since neither I nor my Colleagues know in which direction to go, I kindly ask you lot.
What should I try, read about and do, to resolve my current problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html)?

For your requirement,

(1): GridView can change number of columns by code dynamically (number of rows will be defined automatically by number of items your adapter have). So, if you measure screen size and each ImageButton, you can calculate appropriate rows and columns.

```
    myGridView.setNumColumns(3);
```

(2): width can be expanded to the end of the row by using `android:layout_width="match_parent"` option. In your attached image, you can acheive by below code.

```
<!-- root -->
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <!-- left side -->
    <GridView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" />
    <!-- right side -->
    <GridView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

(3): I recommend you to adjust layout height programatically. Or, just use `layout_widht="wrap_content"` in each `GridLayout` and then adjust padding and margin value of `ImageButton` height. It will give you more visually-arranged result. In general, to calculate by pixel and put the exact value requires many trial-and-error but hard to give satisfactory result. If you do not want to show layout changing to user, you can switch Visibility `INVISIBLE` and `VISIBLE` of each GridLayout.

(4): `GridView` will help you. It can accept `adapter`.

Comment: Not the fastest in things like this. Thanks for an elaboration like that! 
I ll be answering whetever it worked as soon as I ve tested it out.
Greetings

Comment: In the end I did it with the weight attribute and setting height to 0. 
Because our requirements for the project changed (No different Sizes of Battlefields anymore). 
Thank you a lot for your answer. I appreciate it very much! 
Greetings